# How to get image file path in Spring mvc project?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

[image: package explorer]

What my problem is that I can't get image path from the resource folder to main package in spring project. My code is like below.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < SUITE; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < FACE ; j++){

            Card card = new Card();
            BufferedImage temp = null;
            Resource resource = new FileSystemResource("src/main/webapp/resources/img/cards/" + faces[j] + "_of_" + suite[i] + ".png");
            card.setSuite(suite[i]);
            card.setFace(faces[j]);
            card.setValue(values[j]);
            card.setPath(resource.getFilename());

            try {
                temp = ImageIO.read(new File(card.getPath()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            card.setImg(temp);
            deck.add(card);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("img/cards/" + faces[j] + "_of_" + suite[i] + ".png");
```

You can also refrence [Spring Framework Resource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#resources-resourceloader)